# Expressing units as urn's

Tags: uri

I have a program that processes measurements of different types, using different units. For example, kilometers, miles and meters. Or pounds, kilograms and ounces. Each value has to be associated with a unit identifier.

I'm thinking about using urn's, instead of strings, to identify the unit. For example:

```
urn:mycompany.com:unit:distance:mile
urn:mycompany.com:unit:duration:second
urn:mycompany.com:unit:speed:knot
```

But what about using multipliers?

```
urn:mycompany.com:unit:distance:meter
urn:mycompany.com:unit:distance:kilometer
urn:mycompany.com:unit:distance:centimeter
```

I don't like marking each of them as a seperate urn, because they are basically the same unit, just using a different multiplication factor. And besides, it means I have to create 13 different versions of each unit that way.

And what about derived units, such as mph?

```
urn:mycompany.com:unit:speed:mph
urn:mycompany.com:unit:speed:miles_per_hour
urn:mycompany.com:unit:speed:(unit:distance:mile/unit:duration:hour)
```

Somehow I like the latter one the best, but is that even a valid urn? And if not, how can I change it so that it is?

And this is a simple example. Let's take the scientific definition of Joules as kg*m^2/s^2.

```
urn:mycompany.com:unit:energy:(unit:mass:kilogram*unit:distance:meter*unit:distance:meter/(unit:duration:second*unit:duration:second))
```

Comment: Are you forced to deal with both SI and non-SI units? And when you receive a "measurement" is the no context that can tell if we are measuring speed, mass, time, etc?

Comment: Modelling units is difficult. It generally makes sense to distinguish between dimensions and units, and this allows us to thoroughly check for errors (“dimensional analysis”) – a couple of spacecraft were lost for not doing this. However, a full algebra of units can be challenging to implement when considering non-SI systems like CGS, values that are not on a ratio scale such as colour, relativistic effects (since you mention kinetic energy), different kinds of energy, …. Instead: use type systems to model dimensions with an unambiguous internal representation and don't implement an algebra.

Comment: I included the dimension as part of the uri. That is just a choice, I'm not sure yet if I want to stick to it or not. So I would have "unit:distance:mile" and "unit:weight:pound", but "unit:distance:pound" would make no sense. But I could also decide to use "unit:mile" and "unit:pound". As amon already mentioned, you don't want to use algebra. I could say for example, speed is measured in only 3 possible ways (mph, kph, m/s), so I could just make up internal representations.  That's pragmatic. But then I can't use feet per minute or centimeter per year unless I create new uri's for that.